# Wie nennt man Wörter, die so etwas wie ein Merkmal darstellen?

Tags: single-word-request, terminology

Wie nennt man Wörter, die so etwas wie ein Merkmal darstellen, aber (zumindest ursprünglich) keine Bewertung oder Merkmalsausprägung wiedergeben?

Beispiele:

- *Qualität*: Ein gut verarbeitetes Kleidungsstück ist von hoher Qualität.
- *Ästhetik*
- *Quantität*: Eine quantitative Messung ergab, daß 15% der Geräte schon innerhalb der ersten 2 Monate ausfallen.
- *Temperatur*: Morgen wird mit hohen Temperaturen um die 37 °C gerechnet.

Comment: Mir reicht diese Information noch nicht aus, um zu wissen, was du willst. Kannst du vielleicht erklären, inwiefern die Beispiele deiner Beschreibung genügen?

Comment: Es ist nämlich schwer, bewertendere Merkmale als Qualität und Ästhetik zu finden.

Comment: Bitte versuch die Frage durch mehr Informationen zu verbessern, das hört sich interessant an, nur steh ich leider auch an und kann nur ins Blaue schießen ;)

Comment: @thei: Qualität gibt lediglich die Dimension an und ist alleine nicht bewertend. Man spricht beispielsweise von schlechter Qualität, wenn die an ein Produkt gestellten Anforderungen nicht bzw. nur annähernd erfüllt werden.

Comment: @mbx Ok, ich habe inzwischen verstanden, was du willst.

Comment: Ich hätte das so formuliert, dass die angeführten Worte das jeweilige Kriterium angeben, nach dem gemessen wird.

Comment: Wenn das, was man beschreiben will, ein Phasenraum wäre, wäre der gesuchte Begriff "Dimension". Soweit ich weiss gibt es für den genannten Kontext (Bezeichnung von Worten, die eine "Dimension" im Gesprochenen referenzieren) keinen treffenden Begriff. Oder nur einen wissenschaftlichen, den kein Schwein ohne Nachschlagen kennt oder versteht :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In der Philosophie gibt es den Begriff "[Kategorie](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kategorie_%28Philosophie%29)":

> Unter Kategorien (griech. kategoria u. a. Anklage, später Eigenschaft, Aussage oder Prädikat) versteht man in der Logik Grundbegriffe, innerhalb der Ontologie und Metaphysik Grundmerkmale des Seienden. Da das Verb kategorein ins Lateinische übersetzt praedicare lautet, heißen Kategorien insbesondere im Mittelalter auch Prädikamente.

Die Stoiker unterscheiden zum Beispiel folgende vier Kategorien: *Substanz, Beschaffenheit, Eigenschaft und Verhältnis*.

Comment: Das scheint mir zwar ein leicht anderer, enger definiter Kontext zu sein, aber es kommt der Sache schon recht nah. Immerhin beschreiben die dort angeführten Kategorien auch jeweils zugehörige Dimensionen und sind an sich ohne Wertung.

Answer (score 2):

Hhm *Qualität* und *Quantität* könnte ich als **abstrakte Eigenschaften** zusammenfassen.

*Ästhetik* im Sinne von *Schönheit* passt auch dazu.

Im Gegensatz zu den anderen Beispielen wird *Ästhetik* aber nicht nur in diesem Sinne gebraucht.

Z.B. kann *Ästhetik* auch ein **Unterrichtsfach** oder **Kurs** bezeichnen.

Comment: Ästhetik im eigentlichen Sinn gibt doch nur die Wahrnehmbarkeit an und sagt selbst noch nichts darüber aus, wie es von jemandem wahrgenommen wird.

Answer (score 0):

Funktionalbegriff.

Das heißt: Der Begriff bezeichnet eine Abbildung (Funktion) von einem Gegenstand in eine Menge von Werten. -- Beispiel Temperatur: Die Temperatur des Wassers ist 37 Grad. Also, "37 Grad" ist der Wert der Funktion für das Argument "das Wasser". -- Beispiel "Qualität" / "von hoher Qualität" = der Wert der Qualitätsfunktion an dieser Stelle ist im "hohen" Bereich der Wertemenge (das Adjektiv bei einem Funktionalbegriff kann also einen Untertyp der Werte bestimmen).

Siehe zB.: Sebastian Löbner: The Partee Paradox. (darin Abschnitt 3). https://www.ling.hhu.de/fileadmin/redaktion/Oeffentliche_Medien/Fakultaeten/Philosophische_Fakultaet/Sprache_und_Information/Allgemeine_Sprachwissenschaft/Dateien/Sebastian_Loebner/Loebner_Partee_Paradox_in_Semantic_Companion.pdf